# Why I upload the sitemap.xml to google search console xitemap, and it said couldn't find it, how can i solve it

Tags: html, xml, google-search-console

My HTML example is here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Text Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hi welcome to my website</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And i deployed it to netlify already, the URL is:
https://shimmering-marshmallow-5b525b.netlify.app/

after that i use https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ to generate the sitemap.xml and here is my sitemap.xml:

```
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->


<url>
  <loc>https://shimmering-marshmallow-5b525b.netlify.app/</loc>
  <lastmod>2023-07-28T15:52:23+00:00</lastmod>
</url>


</urlset>
```

After i upload to google search console and it said couldn't find, how what should i do now? Thank you for helping.

I have try to use other xml generator and i try the same step, also get the same error